# how to call php script from just server by bash?

Tags: php, bash

i want to execute a php script every day. i have a bash script containing below lines. and i was doing it with that script. but by this way, it can be executed from another computer. lets say webservername="slmnbr" any body can call myscript with

xhttp://slmnbr/myscript.php.

i want to call it from just server.

```
BASE_URL=http://`get-webservername`
/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate --timeout=0 -O - "$BASE_URL/myscript.php"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you should take note that script running in CLI is not the same as running in apache due to different environment between CLI and apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have PHP CLI (command line interface) to do this. It often comes with the PHP installation package (or a separate package).

So as @James mentioned it you need to precede you script name with the CLI PHP executable which in windows is `php.exe` somewhere in your install directory.

In UN*X systems it's somewhere in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/local/bin`. If it is in the PATH you can simply execute it like this:

```
php your_script.php
```

But keep in mind that running your script from server will be not the same as running from a webserver. For e.g. you won't have the `POST` or `GET` variables. So your script may not work.

*Update*

You can make the cron ran scripts unreachable for your webserver by making it unreadable by the user who is running the PHP scripts by the http daemon (usually `www-data`).

I recommend to make it readable only by the user who is running it from cron:

```
chown cronuser your_script.php
chmod 0400 your_script.php
```

*Update2*

If you're running your script in cron with the same user as the webserver does, then at the top of your script stop it from being executed:

```
if (!(php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks Karaszı,

as i understand, i should use /usr/bin/php myscript.php in my bash script, and fix the problems, but it think it is more than this because i can still call it with xhttps://slmnbr/cron/myscript.php. cron is unaccessible (403 Forbidden) but myscript.php is still accessible. can be permissions or any config to make it unaccesible?

Answer (score 1):

To execute a task(or a php script) every day use [cron](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).

The link has all the info you need, including how to prevent external access.

Comment: It's a good idea to include all the info needed for the answer in case tutsplus does not outlive stackoverflow. It's also friendlier not to force anybody to leave the site to get the essentials of either the question or the answer.

Comment: thanks Chris, of course, i m using cron, what i want to learn is how to prevent external access like you said.

Answer (score 0):

With any recent version of "php" you should get a standalone executable called:
"`php.exe`"

Just execute this like so:

```
/usr/local/php.exe your_script.php
```

Comment: having `php.exe` in `/usr/local/` it's a bit crazy :)

Comment: I have only got my Windows XAMP to look at not sure where it goes in the *NIX distributions.

Comment: Oh, sorry I don't know the Windows XAMP.